# For lazy relationship how to specify a fetch join that can force a eager loading in JPA?

Tags: jpa-2.0

```
@Entity
public EntityA implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private EntityB b;
    ...
}
```

How do i dynamically load the EntityB eagerly?

Answer (score 1):

Using a query:

```
select a from EntityA a left join fetch a.b where a.id = :id
```

Comment: would you have a reference please?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: Does not work for me: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list